# Trouble running a make file

Tags: c++, makefile

Here is my make file

cat Makefile

```
# define required macros here
SHELL= /bin/sh

OBJS = main.o factorial.o hello.o
CFLAG = -Wall -g
CC = gcc
INCLUDE =
LIBS  =  -lm

hello:${OBJ} ${CC} ${CFLAGS} ${INCLUDES} -o $@ ${OBJS} ${LIBS}

clean:
   rm -f *.o core *.core

.cpp.o:
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} ${INCLUDES} -c $<
```

Whenever I run make I get the following error

> make
>   Makefile:13: *** missing separator.  Stop.

Where should I put a separator?

Comment: You need to have a `TAB` character instead of spaces at line 13.

Comment: This is probably the single most commonly asked question about using make and writing makefiles.  Even one single search with that error would have found you everything you needed to know.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in line 13: a tab is missing before the rm command (you put some spaces, but instead a tab must be put before each command).

Some further suggestions for a good Makefile:

- Better to add

  ```
  .PHONY:clean
  ```
- Better to use **-Wextra** instead of **-Wall**

Answer (score 1):

A "TAB" character is missing from the beginning of Line 13 in your make file. May be you used spaces instead of TAB